# Lights-out! on a hex grid with buttons on nodes and lights on faces

Tags: reference-request, matching, error-correcting-codes

Consider a truncated hexagonal grid, with some hexagons lit up, such as the one shown below:

[image: truncated hexagonal grid, with some hexagons lit up]

Here the red hexagons are lit up while the dark gray hexagons are not lit up. The grid has buttons (small black circles) that flip the color of adjacent hexagons. There is a button at every node where three hexagons meet, and also at points along the boundary cut where two hexagons meet, and also at the corner points where cuts meet. Buttons at the corners flip one hexagon between lit and unlit. Buttons along the sides simultaneously flip whether the two adjacent hexagons are each lit or not. Buttons in the interior flip the litness of the three adjacent hexagons. This is a variant of the game [Lights Out!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)).

**The goal of the game is to reach the state where all the lights are turned off by pressing as few buttons as possible.**

Is there a polynomial time algorithm for finding a minimum set of button presses? If so, what is it? If not, is there a proof that it isn't such as a reduction from an NP-complete problem?

Note that this problem corresponds to the [decoding problem for the quantum color code](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5738), with the buttons being errors and the faces being stabilizers. Within the quantum error correction community, as far as I know, the solution to this problem is not known. But it's very possible that the wider computer science community already knows the answer. So I am very interested in a solution, or a reference to a solution.

Comment: Can you give a formal definition of your problem?

Comment: @PålGD added pseudocode with pre/postconditions

Comment: Does your path graph approach correctly solve the marked minimum weight perfect matching problem?  I'm skeptical.  What if two paths found during the  all-to-all shortest path search happen to have an edge in common?  In that case it seems like your algorithm could produce an incorrect answer, because it does not account for that possibility.

Comment: Have you tried reducing from [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching)?  Are you able to adapt the reduction from 3SAT to 3-dimensional matching to your situation?  I don't understand what "degree 3 nodes are always between three different colors" means.

Comment: @D.W. When converting back from the path graph reduction, edges are included if they appear in an odd number of the paths (as opposed to if they appear in any path). Version of 1 of pymatching ( https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching/ ) used this approach while version 2 used the more direct approach, and they give identical answers (up to some truncation details for performance).

Comment: @D.W. The 3DM link is interesting. Yeah, that might work for a reduction. It'd have to be a perfect 3DM though.

Comment: @D.W. If a pair of paths between marked nodes $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ shares a subpath between vertices $v,w$ s.t. $a,v,w,c$ and $b,v,w,d$ occur in order (w.l.o.g.), then we can instead match $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ with paths $a,v,b$ and $c,w,d$ that uses no more edges than the earlier pair, and does not use the subpath between $v,w$. Hence, we can always obtain optimal solutions without common edges, which can be found by the method Criag Gidney describes above.

Comment: @Discretelizard, Thanks for the explanation.  That is making more sense, but I'm not convinced yet.  Are we assuming edge weights are non-negative?  The solution for $(a,b)+(c,d)$ uses the edge $(v,w)$ zero times; the solution for $(a,c)+(b,d)$ uses the edge $(v,w)$ either one time or two times, based on whether we require the solution to be a set of paths or a set of edges (the question seems to claim these two are equivalent); and the cost obtained based on the all-to-all shortest paths graph counts the edge $(v,w)$ twice.

Comment: I guess if some edge weights can be negative, then anything based on the all-to-all shortest paths graph is going to struggle, as the distance between many/most pairs of vertices is going to be $-\infty$.

Comment: @D.W. True, my argument requires that the edge-weights are non-negative. Under that condition, I think the two formulations are equivalent. If there are negative weights, they won't, because (as you note) in only one of the two an edge with large negative weight can be taken twice or more.

Comment: @D.W. You can turn negative edge weights into positive edge weights by flipping the markings at both ends of the edge.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the proof for that.  In any case, can you [edit] your question based on all of this discussion to state all requirements (e.g., that all edge weights are non-negative, if that is the case, and an argument for correctness for the algorithm)?

Comment: @D.W. the question already stated that the edge weights are non-negative

Comment: I searched the page and there is nowhere in the text of the question I can find that states edge weights are non-negative.

Comment: @D.W. The python code includes a comment "precondition: non-negative edges" and then an assertion verifying this.

Comment: I know.  That is not a substitute for stating it in the text.  People shouldn't have to dig through the code to understand the problem statement.  Also, I think including an argument for the correctness of the algorithm or reference for that might be valuable to future readers.

Comment: @D.W. I've completely rewritten the question to simplify it.